# Is there a way to read a database link in Cosmos DB Java V4 API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

For example, reading "dbs/colls/document" instead of getting a container, then calling read on the container.

I've been having an issue where the first `readItem` on a container (after calling `database.getContainer(x)`) is extremely slow (like 1 second or longer) and was thinking using a database link could be faster.

I'm guessing a read after getting the container is slow because it doesn't make a service call until I call read.

Is there a way I can have this preloaded when reading in a database?

I have an application with a read(collectionName, key) method, and my approach was to use getContainer(collectionName) and then call read on that, but this method needs to be fast.

Comment: Are you calling getContainer on every request? This is not preferred. You should always try to keep an instance of your container alive between requests and just call readItem on each request.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I changed it to do that, but the latency for every 50 requests or so is really slow (and it's not 429s). I printed diagnostic logs and it looks like, for the slow requests, the "eventName: pipelined" duration is very long. Do you know what this might be from?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, the best practice is to keep an instance of your container alive between requests and call readItem on each request. This should resolve the primary issue.

As for the secondary concern, the "high latency every 50 requests or so", this is a known issue however it should only occur in the first minute or so of operation. If you can tolerate the initial slow requests, the solution is to wait for performance to stabilize. How long do you have to run your app for before you no longer see these high-latency requests?

FYI, if latency is a concern, run your client application in a geographically colocated Azure VM. Also a good rule of thumb is to allocate client CPU cores such that CPU utilization is not more than 40% or 50%.